# Internet Explorer issue with Redirecting

Tags: laravel, internet-explorer, redirect, single-sign-on, microsoft-edge

I've added Single Sign On (SSO) to my Laravel app and am having an issue with Internet Explorer.

When my IdP redirects to my controller, my controller handles the SSO response, logs the user into another API using Guzzle HTTP, then redirects the user to the frontend.

Here is my (shortened) code.

```
    $this->auth->processResponse($_SESSION['AuthNRequestID']);

    // Some error and authentication checks here

    $email = // get email from sso data

    /* Check if a user exists for the given email */

    /* User exists, lets create tokens for the user */
    $ec_api_data = $user->createToken('EC-API-Access-Token');

    /* Log the user in to another API using Guzzle */
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(["verify" => false]);
    $cw_request_data = [
        "form_params" => [
            "login" => $email
            // other params
        ]
    ];

    $res = $client->request('POST', $this->frontend_url . '/auth/api-login', $cw_request_data);
    $cw_api_data = $res->getBody()->getContents();

    // Redirect to the frontend
    header("Location: $this->frontend_url/single-sign-on?email=$email&code=$code");
    die();
```

This code is called when my IdP redirects to my App at /sso/acs. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

In Internet Explorer, when the IdP redirects to my App, it just "Aborted" the request.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth are you using the `$_SESSION` global in a Laravel app? And why are you calling `header()` rather than using Laravel's own tools to redirect it? It wouldn't surprise me if returning a proper response rather than calling `die()` solved the problem.

Comment: Hey Matthew, I am using $_SESSION because the SSO plugin (onelogin-saml-php) stores the data there and I need to retrieve it. I'll change the redirect to use laravel redirect and return a response and try that.

Comment: You'd be much better off seeing if there's a Laravel-specific package for this since that will be much better integrated with Laravel. I found one at https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2 that might be worth a look.

Comment: Just adding a comment for anyone following this post later - the laravel plugin that Matthew mentioned above is good but limited in functionality - in my case I needed to use multiple private keys.